# How to comparison date with timezones on iOS

Tags: ios, datetime, timezone, nsdate, nstimezone

I looking for a way how to comparison date with timezones on ios. It is hard because `NSDate` uses only absolute timezone. I didn't find equivalent of `DateTime` from JodaTime library for iOS.

I would like to implement method:

```
- (BOOL)isTheSameDayForDate:(NSDate *)date1 withTimeZone:(NSTimeZone *)timeZone1 andDate:(NSDate *)date2 withTimeZone:(NSTimeZone *)timeZone2;
```

This method return true if date1 and date2 with their timezones are in the same day from timezone2 perspective.

For: 2014-10-09T03:00:00+03:00 and 2014-10-09T23:00:00+03:00 return YES.

For: 2014-10-09T00:03:00+03:00 and 2014-10-10T00:03:00+03:00 return NO.

It looks easy but please note that for:

2014-10-08T16:00:00-8:00 and 2014-10-09T1:00:00+02:00 return YES

2014-10-08T13:00:00-8:00 and 2014-10-09T1:00:00+02:00 return **NO**

Comment: It's it simply a matter of converting both dates to UTC and comparing them using `[NSDate compare:]`?

Comment: I want to check if these dates are in the same day from timezone2 perspective. @Droppy there is a different meaning of today in different timezones.

Comment: Not when both dates are converted to the same timezone.  It doesn't seem like a difficult problem to solve.

Comment: @Droppy so how to convert date1 to timezone of date2 and compare them if NSDate zone works only in UTC.

Comment: Doesn't `[NSDate date]` return the date in the local timestamp?

Comment: it would be easier to show the implementation of your method, because the system usually compares dates correctly (in `GMT+0`), so I guess you are just overcomplicating something here because you don't need to worry (or even think!) about any timezones, when you'd like to compare two dates to decide whether they represent the same day.

Comment: you may think there is an hour 24, however there is no such hour 24 on a day, that is 0 hour on the next day, therefore the _2014-10-08T16:00:00-8:00_ is __NOT__ equal to _2014-10-08 24:00:00 +0000_ but __IS__ equal to _2014-10-09 00:00:00 +0000_ which is the very next day – while the _2014-10-09T1:00:00+02:00_ is still _2014-10-08 23:00:00 +0000_ on the previous day. (and your algorithm has also a glitch, if it presents different results about those days).

Comment: I have do something at Helsinki in Finland (+2:00) at 1:00 in 9 January. Now I am in San Francisco (-8:00) at 13:00 on 8 January. If I convert these dates to GMT+00:00 I will lose information about timezone, Helsinki time will be convert to 23:00 on 8 January GMT+00:00 and San Francisco will be convert to 21:00 on 8 January GMT+00:00. Now these dates are in the same day 8 January. But from Helsinki time zone perspective San Francisco (-8:00) at 13:00 on 8 January is 23:00 on 8 January (+2:00) so is not the same day like Finland (+2:00) at 1:00.in 9 January.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the new methods on `NSCalendar` that are designed for this purpose. Something like this:

```
NSDate *date1;
NSDate *date2;
NSTimeZone *myTimeZone; // zone of interest

// Set up dates and zone, then do this
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
[calendar setTimeZone:myTimeZone];
BOOL sameDay = [calendar isDate:date1 inSameDayAsDate:date2];
```